# Materialize CSS double autofocus

Tags: css, sass, ruby-on-rails-5, materialize, turbolinks

I have a `Rails 5` app with `turbolinks` + `Materialize css` via [gem](https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass).

I have strange behaviour with "double autofocus" on input:

```
   <div class="form-input input-field">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "validate" %>
      <label for="user_email">Email</label>
    </div>
```

When I'm for the first time on page - it's ok. But when I'm coming there for the second time I have double autofocus. I think, that it can be connected with turbolinks, but I'm not sure.

For better understanding take a look on video, please:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEzTjFniqsY

Why is it so and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When revisiting a page, Turbolinks will display a "preview" of it (if it has a version of that page in its cache). It then loads a fresh page from the server and replaces the preview. So what you're seeing is the field being focussed on the preview, and then refocussed when the fresh copy gets loaded. (There is an argument that Turbolinks should not auto-focus a field in a preview, but here are some possible solutions.)

### Opting out of previews

Turbolinks provides a way to customise caching behaviour. By adding the following meta tag to the head of your page, Turbolinks will not display the preview and will prevent the flickering:

```
<meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-preview">
```

(You could add this to a single page using the `content_for/yield` helpers, or by setting an instance variable in the view.)

The downside of this is that the perceived speed of the page load might be slower because it is not immediately restoring from the cache.

### Remove `autofocus` from preview

Another approach which keeps the preview, is to remove the `autofocus` attribute before the page is cached. This means that the preview's form will not be auto-focussed:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:before-cache', function () {
  $('[autofocus]').removeAttr('autofocus')
})
```

The downside of this approach is that the field won't be focussed if the user accesses the page via the back/forward buttons.

### CSS Solutions

If neither of the above are satisfactory, then you may want to overriding the CSS. The flickering is more noticeable with the materialize CSS which transitions to the focussed styles. <s>So one option would be to override those styles to remove the transition</s>

Another possibility would be to "fake" the non-focussed field style on the preview. Turbolinks adds a `data-turbolinks-preview` attribute to previews, so you could do:

```
html[data-turbolinks-preview] {
  input:focus:not([readonly]) {
    border-bottom: $input-border;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  .input-field {
    .prefix.active {
      color: initial; // Or whatever your default label icon color is
    }

    label:not(.label-icon).active {
      font-size: 1rem; // Or whatever your default label font-size is
      transform: translateY(0);
    }
  }

  input[type=email]:focus:not([readonly]) + label {
    color: $input-border-color; // Or whatever your default label color is
  }
}
```

I generally wouldn't recommend this, as it is overriding a lot of the defaults, which can lead to odd behaviour or maintenance issues, if all the CSS values are not properly reset. It will also make the input appear unfocussed (when it is actually focussed) which may cause some confusion for users. So IMHO one of the previous solutions is preferable to this one.

Hope that's useful.

Comment: Now I see, thank you so much.
Opting out of previews really fixed my issue.

By the way, your CSS solutions doesn't work for me. :( And I really want to have the same loading speed without double autofocus.

Comment: Re: the CSS solutions, I've simulated the flickering situation here: http://output.jsbin.com/tusacut It simulates displaying a preview, then replacing it after 1s. (The source can be found here: http://jsbin.com/tusacut/edit?html,js,output but note, the examples won't work in "Edit mode")

Here is the simulation with the transitions removed (first solution): http://output.jsbin.com/qokobow

And here is the simulation with the non-focussed CSS (second solution): http://output.jsbin.com/tuguken

(Make sure your CSS overrides are included after any CSS which styles the focussed inputs)

Comment: I tried it and placed your css-solution to the end of my css file, but it doesn't help. I think, the key thing is that when you loading page, than going somewhere on site and coming back by link. So after first load it works ok, but after some requests without browser reloading flickering is active.
btw, on your example I can see how "Edit JS bin" button flickering on page loading.

Comment: The CSS has been tested in a Rails app: https://github.com/domchristie/turbolinks_materialize_autofocus You can experiment with the fixes in https://github.com/domchristie/turbolinks_materialize_autofocus/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

Comment: I have added some changes to your project and tested it - it fails for me. I have added sprockets to js, because without it animation doesn't work. Please, update your project according to: https://www.pastiebin.com/5920061143cdb

Comment: Ah OK. The same approach applies to all the other elements: apply a "reset" to make them appear unfocussed. I generally wouldn't recommend this approach as it is making a lot of overrides, which can get messy, but it's up to you :) I have also added another possible solution above: "Remove the autofocus from preview"

Comment: Dom Christie, superb answers. Thank you so much! How did you know about `turbolinks:before-cache` ?

Comment: You're welcome! Details about `turbolinks:before-cache`: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#preparing-the-page-to-be-cached A full list of events: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events I have also raised an issue related to this question here: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/290

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144740/discussion-between-dom-christie-and-tiser).